# How to backup a blog via an RSS feed

Tags: rss, shopify

I'm trying to back up my shopify blog but shopify doesn't have any way to export your blog posts and content. Can this be done somehow using the RSS feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can be done through the RSS feed. It normally returns a limited number of posts e.g. 10.

Comment: Yeah this is the issue I've been running into. I've found that google reader will suck in the entire contents of the feed with all the content in the posts, but I can't figure out a way to get it back out of reader into a useful format.Is there some programatic way to scrape an rss feed and create an xml file with all the posts?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old thread but just in case anyone else was trying to do this I wrote a bit of python code that grabs post content from a shopify blog and saves it to a csv file that can be used to import it into a wordpress blog. It's only the text content of each post at the moment.

http://techasabrick.wordpress.com/2013/07/16/backup-a-shopify-blog-and-import-it-to-wordpress/

Comment: Can you post your steps here, please - in this form your answer is essentially a link-only answer, which are discouraged.